# How to make pdf password protected in yii2 php

Tags: php, yii2, pdf-generation, password-protection, mpdf

I want to make my pdf password protected.

I am using kartik\mpdf\Pdf extension for generating pdf.

```
             $pdf = new Pdf([
                // set to use core fonts only
                'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE,
                // A4 paper format
                'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
                // portrait orientation
                'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
                // stream to browser inline
                'destination' => Pdf::DEST_FILE,
                // your html content input
                'content' => $html,
                // any css to be embedded if required
                'cssFile' => '@api/web/css/notes.css',
                // set mPDF properties on the fly
                'options' => ['title' => $note['title']],
                // call mPDF methods on the fly
                'methods' => [
                    'SetHeader' => [''],
                    'SetFooter' => [''],
                ],
            ]);
            $pdf->content = $html;
            $file_name = "test" . rand(7, 100).pdf";
            $password = "122":
            $pdf->setProtection(array(),$password); 
            $pdf->filename = "uploads/" . $file_name;

            echo $pdf->render();
```

But it gives me error like : **Calling unknown method: kartik\mpdf\Pdf::setProtection();**

I have also tried following code that is putting method after filename :

```
$pdf->filename->setProtection(array(), $password);
```

but it's also give me error like : **Call to a member function setProtection() on string.**

I know the setProtection method is available in vendor's kartik library but i am not sure of how to use it.

Please assist me if anyone has idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$pdf->getApi()->setProtection();
```

Method `getApi()` is to directly call MPDF object and that is where `SetProtection()` method is.